# Set of Structs Missing an Element

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, set

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int dist[2];
struct cmp {
    bool operator() (const int &a, const int &b) {
        return dist[a] < dist[b];
    }
};
set<int, cmp> s;

int main() {
    dist[0] = 2;
    dist[1] = 2;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(0);
    for(set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " " << dist[*it] << endl;
    }
}
```

The above code outputs:

1 2

Why is this true? Should it not output:

1 2

0 2

Thank you!

Comment: The 0 never gets added to s due to the comparison returning false both times (i.e. it considers the values in the set as comparing equal). This question is essentially asking for debugging help and as such is off topic.

Comment: @rex: Since when are questions asking for debugging help off topic?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley  I was mistaken. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` only contains one copy of each *unique* object. When you attempt to insert two objects that are *equivalent* under *weak ordering*, the objects are determined to be not unique, and only the first object remains in the container.

In your code, `0` and `1` are equivalent under weak ordering because of the definition of the comparator. That is:

```
dist[0] = 2;
dist[1] = 2;
cmp compare;
bool res1 = compare(0, 1); //false
bool res2 = compare(1, 0); //false
```

When the comparisons in both directions are false, the two objects are considered equivalent. Only the first one that is inserted is contained in the set.

Use `std::multiset` to allow duplicates.